# access 2010 vba user defined type not defined with FileOpenDialog?

Tags: ms-access-2010

i have a code in vba with access 2010 written inside on click event of a button when i click this it gives me error says "user defined type not defined" this is my code:

```
Private Sub cmdBrowse_Click()
Dim FileOpenDialog As FileDialog
Set FileOpenDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
Dim SelectedFile As Variant
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb
With FileOpenDialog
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Select A File To Use As A Logo"
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Images", "*.gif; *.jpg; *.jpeg;*.bmp;*.png"
    .ButtonName = "Use This File"
   If .Show = True Then
      For Each SelectedFile In .SelectedItems
        Dim LogoFile As String
        LogoFile = SelectedFile
        Dim barewabarayate As Recordset
        Set barewabarayate = db.OpenRecordset("barewabarayate")
        With barewabarayate
            .Edit
            barewabarayate.Fields("image_path") = LogoFile
            barewabarayate.Update
          End With
        Next
    End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you set a reference to Microsoft Office x.x Object Library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree with Remou; I get the same error until I had the following reference in Access 2010:

```
Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library
```

From the VB code editor, select the Tools menu and then References...

Comment: my selected picture is displayed with every record not a specific record can any one help me solve this?

Comment: +1 In Access 2010 and above, you will be prompted : "Would you like to add a reference to the containing library now?" after selecting the built-in variable.

Comment: Remou i do't understand you? i mean with my code when i click a button for getting an image it works success and display image in image control when i click next button it display image with every record in my table?